# If $Y_n\rightarrow c$ in probability does $E(\lvert Y_n - c\rvert)\rightarrow 0$?

Tags: limits, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, expected-value

Let $Y_n$ be real-valued, $c$ a real constant.

If $Y_n\rightarrow c$ in probability, does $E(\lvert Y_n - c\rvert)\rightarrow 0$?

I need this in a larger proof. It seems obvious, but that is often misleading...
I tried
$$E(\lvert Y_n-c\rvert) = E(\lvert Y_n-c\rvert1_{\lvert Y_n-c\rvert > \delta}) + E(\lvert Y_n-c\rvert1_{\lvert Y_n-c\rvert \le \delta}) \le E(\lvert Y_n-c\rvert1_{\lvert Y_n-c\rvert > \delta}) + \delta$$
but I'm having trouble controlling the first term.

How can it be argued?

Comment: Just for information, the converse can be done with Markov's inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general no. As a simple example, consider $Y_n=c$ with probability $1-1/n$ and $c+n$ with probability $1/n$ then $E(|Y_n-c|) \equiv 1$.